# Nested paths don't work when using React Router, BrowserHistory and --history-api-fallback

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am using `browserHistory` and the `--history-api-fallback` flag when running on the webpack dev server to have all URLs default to `index.html`.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={FindUser} />
      <Route path='/users' component={FindUser} />
      <Router path='/users/:id' component={UserPage} />
      <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
      <Route path='/login' component={LogIn} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

All the paths are redirected to the correct component but when I have a nested path such as '/users/123' I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

If I use `hashistory` and put the hashtag before the url parameter, the url works. My assumption is that it can't handle nested path.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: This looks connected with the web server config, this would be for Nginx: `location / { try_files $uri /index.html }`

Comment: What exactly you get when you `curl -I /users/123` ?

Comment: When people have issues with nested routes not loading with React Router, typically the issue is because they are using a relative path in their `index.html` to load their JavaScript files.

Comment: @PaulS You just saved me a massive headache! Sure enough, I had "bundle.js" instead of "/bundle.js" in index.html

Comment: @StephenWidom i was also using the relative path - "bundle.js" instead of "/bundle.js"